# Dependencies for functional testing with geb

Tags: grails, functional-testing, geb, grails-2.5

Does anyone know what the correct dependencies are for functional testing with `geb` in Grails `2.5.0`?

I tried version `0.12.0` of the [Geb Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/geb) but I get the following error:

> Error running forked test-app: No such property: gebPluginDir for
>   class: _Events

Comment: what does your BuildConfig.groovy look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [plugin page](https://grails.org/plugin/geb) your BuildConfig.groovy should look something like this...

```
dependencies {
    compile ":geb:0.12.0"
}

plugins {
    test "org.grails.plugins:geb:0.12.0"
}
```

Though here is my configuration (I use Spock and grails 2.4.5)...

```
dependencies {
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.12.0"
}

plugins {
    test ":geb:0.12.0"
}
```

Comment: good lord...how hard is it for grails plugins developers to get their docs matching their code. LOL